# Triggering an alert with a keypress

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, keypress, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am writing a Greasemonkey script.  I want to trigger a certain code to run when the user presses the "Q" key.  I did a little bit of research, and most of the sources I saw suggested using `window.onkeypress`.

To test this method, I created a userscript set to run when the users presses <kbd>Q</kbd>.  Here is my code:

```
window.onkeypress = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode == 81) {
   alert("This is a test.")
   }
}
```

However, upon pressing the Q key, nothing happened.  I am wondering if anyone knows why this may be and what I can do to correct it.

In addition, if anyone knows of any other methods I can use to achieve the same effect, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`keypress` events don’t receive a `keyCode`; try handling `keydown` instead.

```
window.onkeydown = function(event) {
   if (event.keyCode === 81) {
      alert("This is a test.");
   }
};
```